# SOLVE mysql linux bash with coloumn name have "-" & query mysql from file

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

i have problem with query mysql on linux bash, my query have 2 coloumn with "-" :

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e "select `work-time` from work where `work-time`> '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'";
```

but the result :

```
bash: work-time: command not found
```

i know the problem this quote "`" but how solve this ?

**I UPDATE MY QUERY**

**SOLVE query on line** :

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e "select \`work-time\` from work where \`work-time\`> '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'"
```

**Other Question**

If i save my query on file, and query like this

```
 mysql -u root -pPass mydb < query.sql
```

got error :

```
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\`'.
```

**SOLVE query from file with standard query**

```
select `work-time` from work where `work-time`> '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'
```

save query to file eg. query.sql, and query like this :

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb < query.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mysql and using back ticks in the bash shell**

A query like the following will fail since the back tick character has special meaning in the shell:

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e "select `work-time` from work"
```

The back tick character must either be escaped or used inside a single quoted string when executing sql from the shell. An example of a single quoted string is the following:

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e 'select `work-time` from work'
```

To accomplish the same query using double quotes we would need to escape the back tick character like so:

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e "select \`work-time\` from work"
```

I suggest reading up on the [difference between double quotes and single quotes](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/) in the bash shell.

---

**Example Problem 1:**

```
"select `work-time` from work where `work-time`> '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'"
```

The above query will not work. However, you can accomplish this with single quotes but you will need to escape any single quotes that are inside the query like so:

```
'select `work-time` from work where `work-time`> \'2013-0-3-07 00:00:00\''
```

---

**Example Problem 2:**

```
"select \`work-time\` from work where \`work-time\`> \'2013-0-3-07 00:00:00\'"
```

The above query is almost good as you do need to escape the back tick since it has special meaning. However, you do not need to escape the single quotes. With double quotes the query can look like the following:

```
"select \`work-time\` from work where \`work-time\`> '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'"
```

---

**Back ticks inside a SQL file**

If you then decided you wanted to put this query in a file and send it to mysql you would no longer need to escape the back tick character since the back tick character has no special meaning inside a sql file. In the file you would just put the standard SQL:

```
select `work-time` from work where `work-time` > '2013-0-3-07 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Yes thats work, this issue have solve, but i update my question, if this query on file will error

Comment: I have added your latest query to my answer.

Comment: Hi Brett, yes this solve with remove the quote on '2013-03-07 00:00:00', but i want each my query bookmark on file, so i can query like this : mysql -u root -pPass DBname < query.sql, but error, if my query no have quote "`" the query sucessful. do you have idea ?

Comment: @user1448102 I have updated my answer for your last question regarding sending the query from a file.

Comment: Yes, thats great, yo save my time :)

Answer (score 0):

Text inside backticks is interpreted as a command when used bare or inside double quotes.

You need to use single quotes:

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e 'select `work-time` from work'
```

Alternatively, you can escape the backticks:

```
mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e "select \`work-time\` from work"
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, but this will error if my query like this :   mysql -u root -pPass mydb -e 'select `work-time` from work' where `work-time` > '2013-03-05 00:00:00' '  ?

Comment: @user1448102 I've added an example for double quotes too.

Comment: Yes, thats work, but i have other issue, if my query on file like mysql -u root -pPass work   < query.sql  
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\`'.

Comment: @user1448102 That makes no sense at all, and doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: I have try query mysql from file like this "select * from user" (user.sql) and i call this query on bash like this : mysql -u root -pPass mysql < user.sql this success query if no quote "`" on my query.

Comment: @user1448102 Then you have an error in your .sql file; that's not related to bash.

Comment: Hi Jack, i mean write query "select \\`work-time\\` from work" to file query.sql but if use query from file with this query thats make error, if i write query on standard query like Brett shown thats OK, thanks for your help, this case have solved.

Comment: @user1448102 You can't use \\` in SQL itself of course; escaping like that is only needed in bash itself.